# What is a proper way to acknowledge an MQ message from a chain of actors?

Tags: rabbitmq, akka, message-queue

We want to use Akka to implement a scenario when messages are fetched from a message queue (RabbitMQ) and then processed by a chain of actors. The queue is durable and messages must not be lost. So we need to send an acknowledgement (BasicAck in RabbitMQ) back to the queue in order to finalize the dequeued message. Because of that the very last actor in the processing chain needs to do the acknowledgement. This seems to be rather common need, and I wonder if there is a known pattern for this. Vaughn Vernon in his book writes about using Return Address, so all messages sent along the chain will have the return address (of the MQ channel actor) and the correlation identifier that specifies the queue message tag. Is this the proper way to do it?

An alternative is to ack the message right after the receival and then use persistent actors to provide its guaranteed delivery, but I was adviced against such approach because use of AMPQ eliminates the need for actor persistance for this particular scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with Akka, but I think I get the gist of what it does (very similar to "process" in Erlang - i think - which is what RMQ is built on).

In general, your first suggestion from Vaughn Vernon's book is the way to go.

In my specific scenarios, I have taken a "middleware" approach to what you are suggesting. My specific middleware implementation forwards the message itself through a chain of commands that process the message. Each command calls an `action.next()` method to continue forwarding to the next command.

Prior to sending the message through the middleware, I create a default last-command-in-the-chain. This default command simply calls `actions.ack()` - which, behind the scenes, acknowledged the message.

I do things this way so that the commands never have to know anything about how to actually implement the mechanics of completing and moving on to the next thing. They have an API specific to themselves, being commands in a chain.

This allows me to change the implementation of acknowledging the message, or how i handle messages from RMQ, etc, without changing the commands directly.

Ack'ing the message immediately introduces danger, as your actor could crash, Akka itself could crash, and a host of other problems can (and will) occur, and you'll be more likely to lose the message.

Remember, though - there is not 100% perfect setup. You will, at some point, lose a message or process the same message twice. Your system needs to handle these scenarios in some way, at some point. Everything your doing is heading down the right path to make this less likely, but nothing will ever prevent crashes and message loss 100% of the time.

Comment: Thank you Derick for the suggestion and sharing your experience.